# Print out server's own public key using PHP

Tags: php, public-key-encryption

I want to print out my own server's public key using PHP.
So what i want is that a php file that echoes the public key of the server it is being hosted on. Is there a pre-built function for it ?
thanks

Comment: do you mean the ssl certificate?

Comment: well the key is just a text file so you can read it using the answer in method shown below. That should work.

Comment: Every server hosting https has a public key and the private key. The ssl certificate has the public key.

Answer (score 0):

well I am not aware of any pre-built function that does that. To answer your question correctly, you should provide more information about the server and especially what you mean by your server's public key. Any server can generate as many SSH key-pairs as he likes.

Just a guess that might help you: Look in the .ssh folder. If there is a file called id_rsa.pub, I would go for that one. Then use a pre-build PHP function to read the contents of that file.

Cheers

Comment: Every server using https has its unique public key. Its stored in the certificate. I want to print out that public key.

Answer (score 0):

Run your script from the folder required and use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) like this

```
$content = file_get_contents("yourkey.extension");

echo $contents; // Wherever you need this in your script
```

If you mean SSL key decryption then see [openssl_private_decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) function.

Hope that helps :)